# Customize addresses fields on WooCommerce My account and Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter to edit the value of woocommerce field labels. It works fine on the checkout page (as you might expect), however I cannot understand why it doesn't also take effect on the account pages. I thought these fields were still taken form the same place? More specifically, I'm talking about the address fields on the edit-address endpoint on woocommerce account pages?

My code attempt:

```
function custom_woocommerce_fields( $fields ) {

    // Billing Fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'First name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['label'] = 'Last name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['label'] = 'Company name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Street address';
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label'] = 'Apartment, unit, etc.';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = 'City';
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['label'] = 'Country';
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['label'] = 'County/State';
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = 'Email';
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';

    // Shipping Fields
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['label'] = 'First name';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['label'] = 'Last name';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['label'] = 'Company name';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']['label'] = 'Street address';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['label'] = 'Apartment, unit, etc.';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['label'] = 'City';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['label'] = 'Country';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['label'] = 'County/State';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_email']['label'] = 'Email';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';

    // Account Fields
    $fields['account']['account_username']['label'] = 'Username or email';
    $fields['account']['account_password']['label'] = 'Password';

    // Order Fields
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Order notes';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_woocommerce_fields' );
```

Fields doesn't get customized on My account > Addresses (edit billing or shipping address).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` **only allow customizations on checkout page** and will **not affect** the My account "Addresses" section fields.

The following will affect both **My account "Addresses"** section fields and checkout fields, allowing to make billing and shipping fields customized also on the related my account section.

---

1) For addresses fields *(both billing and shipping)* on My account and checkout:

In some cases you need to use this filter for addresses fields and it's applied to all **billing and shipping default fields**:

```
// Billing and Shipping fields on my account edit-addresses and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['first_name']['label'] = 'First name';
    $fields['last_name']['label'] = 'Last name';
    $fields['company']['label'] = 'Company name';
    $fields['address_1']['label'] = 'Street address';
    $fields['address_2']['label'] = 'Apartment, unit, etc.';
    $fields['city']['label'] = 'City';
    $fields['country']['label'] = 'Country';
    $fields['state']['label'] = 'County/State';
    $fields['postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';

    return $fields;
}
```

You can use WooCommerce conditional tags is_account_page() and is_checkout() to target my account pages or checkout page…

---

2) For Billing fields on my account edit-addresses and checkout:

```
// Billing fields on my account edit-addresses and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_billing_fields' );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    // Billing Fields
    $fields['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'First name';
    $fields['billing_last_name']['label'] = 'Last name';
    $fields['billing_company']['label'] = 'Company name';
    $fields['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Street address';
    $fields['billing_address_2']['label'] = 'Apartment, unit, etc.';
    $fields['billing_city']['label'] = 'City';
    $fields['billing_country']['label'] = 'Country';
    $fields['billing_state']['label'] = 'County/State';
    $fields['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';
    $fields['billing_email']['label'] = 'Email';
    $fields['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';

    return $fields;
}
```

---

3) For Shipping fields on my account edit-addresses and checkout

```
// Shipping fields on my account edit-addresses and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'custom_shipping_fields' );
function custom_shipping_fields( $fields ) {

    // Shipping Fields
    $fields['shipping_first_name']['label'] = 'First name';
    $fields['shipping_last_name']['label'] = 'Last name';
    $fields['shipping_company']['label'] = 'Company name';
    $fields['shipping_address_1']['label'] = 'Street address';
    $fields['shipping_address_2']['label'] = 'Apartment, unit, etc.';
    $fields['shipping_city']['label'] = 'City';
    $fields['shipping_country']['label'] = 'Country';
    $fields['shipping_state']['label'] = 'County/State';
    $fields['shipping_postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';
    $fields['shipping_email']['label'] = 'Email';
    $fields['shipping_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';

    return $fields;
}
```

---

4) All (other) fields only on checkout:

```
// All fields only on checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'other_custom_checkout_fields' );
function other_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Account Fields
    $fields['account']['account_username']['label'] = 'Username or email';
    $fields['account']['account_password']['label'] = 'Password';

    // Order Fields
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Order notes';

    return $fields;
}
```

---

5) Also depending on the selected country, you should need to use the filters:

- `woocommerce_country_locale_field_selectors`
- `woocommerce_get_country_locale_default`

Those are located on `WC_Country` Class.

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

Related official documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)