# removing Woocommerce billing fields doesn't remove it from my account billing addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

we achieved to hide the unwanted billing fields from the checkout page but they still appear in the billing fields of my account addresses pages:

[image]

```
/**
 Remove all possible fields
 **/
function wc_remove_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Billing fields
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_country'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_state'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] );

    // Order fields
     unset( $fields['order']['order_comments'] );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_remove_checkout_fields' );
```

we need them to be hidden there too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize addresses fields on WooCommerce My account and Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729859/customize-addresses-fields-on-woocommerce-my-account-and-checkout)

Comment: @7uc1f3r i think yes sir, thank you so much

Comment: @7uc1f3r have a help heere? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129994/synchronize-woocommerce-billing-email-with-wordpress-email